# How to disappear a warning message from the Cognos Dashboard visualization?

Tags: dashboard, cognos, cognos-11

I have a visualization on dashboard (**cognos 11.1.4**) which is a bar chart. When my displayed data is too much a *warning message* (a yellow triangle with an exclamation mark) appears at the upper right corner of the visualization with the following message : `The data displayed has been limited.`
Do you know how to disappear this message ?

Comment: 1) Do you have access to the model and framework manager?
The model/metadata may need to be reviewed
2) Do you have the SQL statement the query is generating for that widget?
Might be able to optimize the query

Comment: VAI Jason  Yes, I have access to the package.

Comment: great, can you pre-total the result for the element in the dashboard?

Comment: VAI Jason No. The warning message appears due to the fact that,  on the bar chart I use the  Repeat (column) field. As a result nested bar charts appear in the visualization and the warning message displayed.

Comment: The limit is 3000 data points, which is a lot, probably far more than could be displayed and provide much meaning, if at all. 

Removing the warning, assuming that it could be done, would not deal with the issue of having rather too many data points. It would only cause people not to know, other than having lots of very thin, not very easy to see, bars in their difficult to view chart, that the issue exists.

It is possible that the non-displayed data points could affect how the chart renders and alter the viewer's perception of the chart's meaning.

Comment: The realistic approach would be to filter the chart by some attribute. Or not do the nesting.

Do you get better results if you use a line chart?

What data are you trying to track?  What is the purpose of the chart?  Why do you need so many data points? Or is it just a matter of someone asked for it and yours is not to reason why?

Comment: @C'est Moi The vidualization I have is a  Bar chart and I use the folowing measures and dimensions: Actual Duration (Min), Months & Countries. So I use the Repeat Row property=Countries of the Visualization. As a result I have visualization with multiple bar sharts, 1 bar chart/Country. This is I want, but the warning message appears due to the fact that I have 140 countries. So the cognos cannot appear all of them . Thats why I want to dissapear  the triangle.

Comment: I have the feeling that you have not read what I've said very carefully so I'll try to explain in rephrased terms.  1.  The only way to prevent the warning is to have your chart limited to a reasonable number of data points. 2. So many data points is unreasonable and will probably not convey much meaning. 3.Removing the warning (which you can't) would mislead your users about what possible data exists. 4.   It is possible that the non-displayed data points could affect how the chart renders and alter the viewer's perception of the chart's meaning.

Comment: Rethink what your reporting requirements are.  What is the purpose of the chart? Why do you need so many data points? Or is it just a matter of someone asked for it and yours is not to reason why?

Comment: @ C'est Moi You answer to my question ''3.Removing the warning (which you can't)'' (sic) That's all I need to know.